# How to graph individual Summary metric instances in Prometheus?

Tags: monitoring, latency, summary, prometheus

I'm using Prometheus' `Summary` metric to collect the latency of an API call.  Instead of making an actual API call, I'm simply calling `Thread.sleep(1000)` to simulate a 1 second api-call latency value -- this makes the `Summary` hold a value of .01 (for 1 second of latency).  But if, for example, I invoke `Thread.sleep(1000)` twice in the same minute, the `Summary` metric ends up with a value of .02 (for 2 seconds of latency), instead of two individual instances of .01 latency that just happened to occur within the same minute. My problem is the Prometheus query. The Prometheus query I am currently using is: `rate(my_custom_summary_sum[1m])`.

What should my Prometheus query be, such that I can see the latency of **each individual `Thread.sleep(1000)` invocation**.  As of right now, the `Summary` metric collects and displays the total latency sum per minute.  How can I display the latency of each **individual** call to `Thread.sleep(1000)` (i.e. the API request)?

```
private static final Summary mySummary = Summary.build()
                                        .name("my_custom_summary")
                                        .help("This is a custom summary that keeps track of latency")
                                        .register();

Summary.Timer requestTimer = mySummary.startTimer(); //starting timer for mySummary 'Summary' metric
        Thread.sleep(1000); //sleep for one second
        requestTimer.observeDuration(); //record the time elapsed
```

This is the graph that results from this query: 
[Prometheus graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpzDW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is a metrics-based monitoring system, it cares about overall performance and behaviour - not individual requests.

What you are looking for is a logs-based system, such as Graylog or the ELK stack.